# @selector - With Multiple Arguments?

Tags: objective-c

I have been using `@selector` today for the first time and have not been able to work out how to do the following? How would you write the `@selector` if you had more than one argument?

No arguments:

```
-(void)printText {
    NSLog(@"Fish");
}

[self performSelector:@selector(printText) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.25];
```

Single argument:

```
-(void)printText:(NSString *)myText {
    NSLog(@"Text = %@", myText);
}

[self performSelector:@selector(printText:) withObject:@"Cake" afterDelay:0.25];
```

Two arguments:

```
-(void)printText:(NSString *)myText andMore:(NSString *)extraText {
    NSLog(@"Text = %@ and %@", myText, extraText);
}

[self performSelector:@selector(printText:andMore:) withObject:@"Cake" withObject:@"Chips"];
```

Multiple Arguments: (i.e. more than 2)

[`NSInvocation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsinvocation)

Comment: Updated to reflect answers, thanks for all the help, much appreciated.

Comment: your "double arguments" don't have a delay

Answer (score 40, accepted):

```
 - (id)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector
           withObject:(id)anObject  
           withObject:(id)anotherObject
```

From the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418956-nsobject/1418667-performselector?language=objc):

> This method is the same as [performSelector:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418956-nsobject/1418867-performselector?language=objc) except that you can supply two arguments for aSelector. aSelector should identify a method that can take two arguments of type id. For methods with other argument types and return values, use [NSInvocation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsinvocation).

so in your case you would use:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(printText:andMore:)
           withObject:@"Cake"
           withObject:@"More Cake"]
```

Answer (score 19):

As an alternative for NSInvocation when you have more than two parameters, you can use NSObject's [-methodForSelector:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/instanceMethodForSelector:) as in the following example:

```
SEL a_selector = ...
Type1 obj1 = ...
Type2 obj2 = ...
Type3 obj3 = ...
typedef void (*MethodType)(id, SEL, Type1, Type2, Type3);
MethodType methodToCall;
methodToCall = (MethodType)[target methodForSelector:a_selector];
methodToCall(target, a_selector, obj1, obj_of_type2, obj_of_type3);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  I needed to be able to pass in the parameters by reference, and couldn't figure out how to do it with performSelector.  I did figure it out with NSInvocation, but I kept getting malloc errors.  This did exactly what I needed it to do.

Answer (score 14):

I had an issue where I needed to use the `afterDelay` along with multiple arguments to my `@selector` method. Solution? Use a wrapper function!

Say this is the function I *want* to pass to `@selector`:

```
-(void)myFunct:(NSString *)arg1 andArg:(NSString *)arg2 andYetAnotherArg:(NSString *)arg3;
```

Obviously, I can't even use `withObject: withObject:` here, so, make a wrapper!

```
-(void)myFunctWrapper:(NSArray *)myArgs {
    [self myFunct:[myArgs objectAtIndex:0] andArg:[myArgs objectAtIndex:1] andYetAnotherArg:[myArgs objectAtIndex:2]];
}
```

and use it by doing:

```
NSArray *argArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:string1,string2,string3,nil];
[self performSelector:@selector(myFunctWrapper:) withObject:argArray afterDelay:1.0];
```

This way I can have multiple arguments *and* use the selector with delay.

Comment: Those things you call functions are actually called methods. Not only in Objective-C, but in all serious programming languages this distinction is made. To be precise: as soon as this thing is attached to an object, it's a method. Standing alone it's called a function.

Comment: For the general case I tend to use a dictionary to pass the parms.  You're not order-dependent and you can easily have optional parms, etc.

Answer (score 4):

```
@selector(printText:andMore:)
```

Comment: thank you, but how would I specify the arguments @"Cake" and @"More Cake"?

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use an even shorter syntax:

```
#import <objc/message.h> // objc_msgSend
...
((void (*)(id, SEL, Type1, Type2, Type3))objc_msgSend)(target, a_selector, obj1, obj_of_type2, obj_of_type3);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[self performSelector:@selector(printText:andMore) withObject:@"Cake" withObject:@"More Cake"];
```

Comment: There is `-performSelector:withObject:withObject:` and `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`, but the mix of the two does not exist.

Comment: Right you are. I was copy/pasting and made a mistake. Good spot

Answer (score 2):

Elaborating on [Ben-Uri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11906631/405865), which can be written way shorter.

E.g. calling the `UIView` method `- (CGPoint)convertPoint:(CGPoint)point toView:(UIView *)view` can 
be done as follows:

```
SEL selector = @selector(covertPoint:toView:);
IMP method = [viewA methodForSelector:selector];
CGPoint pointInB = method(viewA, selector, pointInA, viewB);
```

Comment: Based on this SO post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952996/why-does-this-code-give-exc-bad-access-using-imp) you will have memory problems done this way if you have ARC enabled.

Answer (score 1):

As KennyTM pointed out, the selector syntax is

```
@selector(printText:andMore:)
```

You call it with

```
performSelector:withObject:withObject.
```

... if you need more arguments or different types, you need to use [NSIvocation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInvocation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSInvocation)

Answer (score 1):

Using **NSInvocation** as you specify you can create an NSObject category that implements

```
- (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObjects:(NSArray *)arguments;
```

Something like:

```
- (void)performSelector:(SEL)aSelector withObjects:(NSArray *)arguments
{
    NSMethodSignature *signature = [self methodSignatureForSelector: aSelector];
    NSInvocation *invocation = [NSInvocation invocationWithMethodSignature: signature];
    [invocation setSelector: aSelector];

    int index = 2; //
    for (NSObject *argument in arguments) {
        [invocation setArgument: &argument atIndex: index];
        index ++;
    }
    [invocation invokeWithTarget: self];
}
```

from: [iOS - How to implement a performSelector with multiple arguments and with afterDelay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439052/ios-how-to-implement-a-performselector-with-multiple-arguments-and-with-afterd/55955055#55955055)