# pass two arguments with performSelector method

Tags: iphone, xcode

```
-(void)application :(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{

    [self addMessageFromRemoteNotification:userInfo updateUI:NO];

}
```

I need to run above method in performSelectorInBackground method.but there is option with single object.How do i change my code?

Comment: Wrap the objects you need to send in an array. :)

Comment: I believe this is what you're looking for as a reference:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439052/ios-how-to-implement-a-performselector-with-multiple-arguments-and-with-afterd

Answer (score 2):

use GCD:

```
-(void)application :(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        [self addMessageFromRemoteNotification:userInfo updateUI:NO];
    });

}
```

dispatch_async returns immediately, and then the block will execute asynchronously in the background.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to pass multiple parameters via performSelectorInBackground. The way I solve the issue when I encounter it is passing a dictionay, this is made easier with the literal NSDictionary syntax.

```
-(void)application :(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(backgroundMethod:) withObject:@{@"userInfo" : someUserInfoDictionary, @"updateUI" : @(NO)}];
}
-(void)backgroundMethod:(NSDictionary *)params
{
    [self addMessageFromRemoteNotification:params[@"userInfo"] updateUI:[params[@"updateUI"] boolValue]];
}
```

Comment: [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(backgroundMethod:) withObject:@{@"userInfo" : userInfo, @"updateUI" : @(NO)}];