# how to pass multiple parameters with selector method

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

i have a slider which i create programmatically

```
UISlider *mySlider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30,mainCategory.frame.size.height+subCategory.frame.size.height+questionLabel.frame.size.height +offsetQuestion,433,38)];
[mySlider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderAction::) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[mySlider setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
mySlider.minimumValue = 0;
mySlider.maximumValue = 100;

mySlider.continuous = YES;
mySlider.value = 0;
```

but i need to send questionID parameter to sliderAction method
and here is the sliderAction method:

```
-(void)sliderAction:(int)questionID :(id)sender
{
    int discreteValue = roundl([(UISlider*)sender value]);

    UILabel *mylabel = (UILabel *)[self.scrlview.superview viewWithTag:questionID];
    mylabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",discreteValue];
    NSLog(@"%d",[sender tag]);
}
```

i don't know how to call it with questionID

Comment: You can use NSArray or NSDictionary as parameter. See this link -------

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439052/ios-how-to-implement-a-performselector-with-multiple-arguments-and-with-afterd

Comment: The action event method (for example methods for handle button click, slider value change, etc.) needs to take just one parameter. Please explain more what you are trying to do (where do you get this questionId from?) and I'm sure someone helps you.

Comment: i want to generate dynamic form. and if question type for example slider i create it and add to scrollview. i also want to show value of slider with a uilabel. if i statically add label tag the above code works fine. But it should be dynamic and there could be many slider questions. so i need to pass questionID to know which label i write the value

Comment: if I'd need an integer value and I were you, I'd use the `tag` property of the `UIView` passing a value over.

Comment: yes i tried that but the problem is while i create a slider control i also create a label control to set slider's value. so in for loop both of them take the same tag and in sliderAction method viewWithTag gives error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do such a thing here:

```
UISlider *mySlider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30,mainCategory.frame.size.height+subCategory.frame.size.height+questionLabel.frame.size.height +offsetQuestion,433,38)];
[mySlider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[mySlider setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
mySlider.minimumValue = 0;
mySlider.maximumValue = 100;
mySlider.continuous = YES;
mySlider.value = 0;
mySlider.tag = // ... your question ID or whatever.
```

and:

```
- (void)sliderAction:(UISlider *)sender {

    NSInteger questionID = sender.tag;

    int discreteValue = roundl([(UISlider*)sender value]);
    UILabel *mylabel = (UILabel *)[self.scrlview.superview viewWithTag:questionID];
    mylabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",discreteValue];
    NSLog(@"%d",[sender tag]);
}
```

Comment: yes i tried that but the problem is while i create a slider control i also create a label control to set slider's value. so in for loop both of them take the same tag and in sliderAction method viewWithTag gives error

Comment: you may want to use an offset for the `UILabel` objects, like e.g. `UILabel` objects start from `1000` the `UISlider` objects start from `0`, and there won't be interference between the `tag` values when you call the `–viewWithTag:` method, you just need to increase the question ID by `1000` and those will be your labels' `tag` values, e.g. the `tag` `12` of `UISider` will match the `tag` `1012` of `UILabel`, etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can't make UIControlEvents selector to have multiple parameters.

But you can do like so,

```
UISlider *mySlider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(30,mainCategory.frame.size.height+subCategory.frame.size.height+questionLabel.frame.size.height +offsetQuestion,433,38)];

[mySlider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

[mySlider setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
mySlider.minimumValue = 0;
mySlider.maximumValue = 100;

mySlider.continuous = YES;
mySlider.value = 0;





-(void)sliderAction:(id)sender
{

    [self slider:(UISlider *)sender withQuestionID:1 Or YourOwnValue here];

}


-(void)slider:(UISlider*)slider withQuestionID:(int)questionID
{

    int discreteValue = roundl([slider value]);

    UILabel *mylabel = (UILabel *)[self.scrlview.superview viewWithTag:questionID];
    mylabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",discreteValue];
    NSLog(@"%d",[slider tag]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can pass a single object as parameter.
So you have to pass an `NSDictionary` and the read the data using specific keys.

Comment: Can you show example how to pass an dictionary to UISlider action method?

Comment: ok i want to send an integer and sender. how can i add these two to a dictionary?