# how to pass five value in the method calling in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c

**My code here(METHOD DEFINITION)**

```
- (void)info:(NSString *)idno info1:(NSString *)package info2:(NSString *)rate info3:(NSString *)type info4:(NSString *)status;
{
  //CODE HERE
}
```

**My code here(METHOD CALLING)**

```
[self performSelector:@selector(info:info1: info2:info3:info4:) withObject:@"a" withObject:@"b" withObject:@"c" withObject:@"d" withObject:@"e"  ];
```

MY app displays the fallowing error:

> No visible @interface for 'ViewController' declares the selector 'performSelector:withObject:withObject:withObject:withObject:withObject:'

Please help how to solve this problem

Comment: Instead of five param, pass one dict.

Comment: What actually you trying to do pls explain may be we give you better option than you trying.

Comment: how to pass one dic please give me simple example

Comment: `performSelector` is not intended to call a function with more than one argument. Then use some packing structure (dictionary, structure, etc) to pass a single argument.

Comment: Please explain what is the your requirement. Are you wanted to pass value within a class with func ??

Comment: May I know where you have write this code: performSelector Is it in cellForRowAtIndexPath? Could you please share what you actually want to implement?

Comment: my method takes five argument and I try to pass five value when I am calling my method

Comment: your param seems an attributes of an Object. Do you have an array of objects?

Comment: I write this in (void)viewDidLoad

Comment: Just take instance variables of class: package, rate etc. and you can access them directly in your action method: info:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can directly called the method as like instead of `performSelector`

```
[self info:@"a" info1:@"b" info2:@"c" info3:@"d" info4:@"e" ];
```

else if you want to continue your work with the help of performselector see this already answered in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439052/ios-how-to-implement-a-performselector-with-multiple-arguments-and-with-afterd)

Answer (score 2):

This is how you have to do.

in `viewDidLoad`

```
// create a dict 

NSDictionary *myDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: @"my_pack" , @"package" , @"my_rate" , @"rate" ,  @"my_type", @"type" , @"my_status", @"status" , nil];

// Call your func

[self passMyValueHere:myDict];
```

your func

```
- (void) passMyValueHere : (NSDictionary *) myValues{

}
```

Comment: directly call [self info:pass your argments];

Comment: @MohamedAli What is the issue?? Calling a func with multiple params or storing values into DB??

Comment: both I want  Calling a func with multiple params and when my function gets these value must store values into sqlite DB my inserting code here: NSString *strsave = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"insert into internet_rate values('%@','%@','%@' ,'%@' ,'%@')",idno  ,package , rate,status ,type];
    dboperation *ds = [[dboperation alloc]init];
    BOOL st = [ds getalluser:strsave];
    if (st)
    {
        NSLog(@"data is save");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"data is not save");
    }

Comment: @MohamedAli Its a different ques, so better if you post new ques bcz here the quest is how to pass five values.

Comment: It's much easier to create an `NSDictionary` using literals: `NSDictionary *myDict = @{@"my_pack" : @"package" , @"my_rate" : @"rate"};`