# NSInvocation and ARC (Automatic Reference Counting)

Tags: cocoa, automatic-ref-counting, nsinvocation

When trying to migrate my current code to ARC, I'm getting errors whenever I pass an NSString as an NSInvocation argument.

Example:

```
NSInvocation inv = ...;
NSString *one = @"Hello World!";
[inv setArgument:&one atIndex:2];
```

The error happens when I use the Refactor -> Convert to Objective-C ARC option from the Edit menu.  The text is "NSInvocation's setArgument is not safe to be used with an object with ownership other than __unsafe_retained."

How would I get around this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This might work;

```
__unsafe_unretained NSString *one = @"Hello World";
```

Comment: This will work, but you have to be VERY careful with the memory handling on this. I would recommend not using NSInvocation anymore if you can avoid it...

Comment: I am using OCMock, and it passes an NSInvocation object into its callback blocks. If you don't use __unsafe_unretained on all the parameters ARC gets very unhappy. So thanks for the tip, mysterious crashes gone!

Answer (score 5):

As Joshua Weinberg commented, using NSInvocation is not recommended anymore.
If you have up to two parameters you can use performSelector.
For three parameters or more, you can use NSObject's [-methodForSelector:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297613/selector-with-multiple-arguments/11906631#11906631) as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297613/selector-with-multiple-arguments/11906631#11906631).