# How to supress warning on the line on Objective-C compiler?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

How to supress a warning on the line on Objective-C compiler?

```
...
[[UIWebDocumentView class] jr_swizzleMethod:@selector(canPerformAction:withSender:) withMethod:@selector(myCanPerformAction:withSender:) error:nil]; // warning here
...
```

NSObject has this method (as category). But compiler thinks that UIWebDocumentView doesn't. This is a compiller's issue. Is there any directive to suppress warnings on a block of the code?

The warning:

> Receiver 'UIWebDocumentView' is a forward class and corresponding
>   @interface may not exist

P.S. `UIWebDocumentView` is a private API - so can't use `performSelector` method tu supress the warning.

Comment: Please your question and add the line and the **exact warning text**.

Comment: I want to find a way to suppress any warning.

Comment: [@selector - With Multiple Arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297613/selector-with-multiple-arguments)

Comment: Suppressing the warning is the wrong thing to do much of the time.  The *correct* fix is to make sure you're `#import`ing the correct header files so that the compiler is aware of the category.

Comment: I have not correct header file - this is a private API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to fix this is just to get the class a different way:

```
[NSClassFromString(@"UIWebDocumentView") jr_swizzleMethod:@selector(canPerformAction:withSender:) withMethod:@selector(myCanPerformAction:withSender:) error:nil]; // warning here
```

Answer (score 4):

Generally, you can ignore warnings for a single line of code like this:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Warc-performSelector-leaks"
[foo bar];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

replace `-Warc-performSelector-leaks` with the actual warning.

Since you didn't post the exact warning you have to figure out the -WarnLevel on your own.

Comment: I have added the actual warning to the question.

Comment: The warning is: `Receiver 'UIWebDocumentView' is a forward class and corresponding @interface may not exist.`